# how can i get specific data between div with file_get_content

Tags: php

suppose i echo out

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com";
echo file_get_content($url);
```

and http://www.mydomain.com has a div i.e

```
<title>sitename</title>
</head><body>
Lorem Ipsum.......
<div id="divname">and here is div content</div>
Copyright bla bla bla
```

no i want to only fetch content between div with id="divname" how can i do that

Comment: how do you plan to handle: `<div id="divname">and here is div content<div id="divname">and another in a deeper level</div></div>`

Comment: Outputting duplicate IDs is grounds for 50 lashes with a moldy ramen noodle.

Comment: @stillstanding: duplicate id's are not valid xhtml - hey have to be unique to the entire document. if this situation comes up "youre doing it wrong" and Marc B's suggested punishment is justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com";
$html =  new SimpleXmlElement($url, null, true);

$content = $html->xpath("//div[@id='divname']");
```

Of course you could still use `file_get_contents` or `curl` if you want to introduce error checking on the fetch of the document.

Answer (score 0):

With [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$ret = $html->find('div[id=divname]');
```

Comment: Raw PHP doesn't have a file_get_html() function

Comment: You should add that you’re using [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, is necessary use SImple HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: Well, then add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$html = file_get_html('http://www.mydomain.com');
foreach($html->find('div#divname') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext;

Here as "divname" is an id so we have used # so if you have any class then you may use .(dot)